# Determine those values of $r$ for which $f'(0)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> If $r>0$ is a rational number, let $f:R \to R$ be defined by
>   $f(x)=x^rsin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)= 0$. Determine those
>   values of $r$ for which $f'(0)$ exists.

for $f'(0) $ to exist I need to consider $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \lim_{x\to 0}x^{r-1}sin(1/x)$

$r>0 \Rightarrow r-1 >-1$

So if $r-1 >0$ or $r>1$ I know the limit will exist and equal zero{squeeze theorem}. Also if $r-1 = 0 $ or $ r =1$ $\lim_{x\to 0}sin(1/x) $ wont exist. But how can I decide for $(r-1) \in ]-1,0[$ or $r \in ]0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $r-1\in]-1,0[$, you have
$$\lim_{x\searrow 0} x^{r-1}=\infty.$$
Now choose two sequences (Try to write them down explicitly) $x_k\searrow 0$ and $y_k\searrow 0$ such that
$$\sin\frac{1}{x_k}=1 \mbox{ and } \sin\frac{1}{y_k}=0.$$
Now determine the results of 
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}x_k^{r-1}\sin\frac{1}{x_k}\mbox{ and }\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}y_k^{r-1}\sin\frac{1}{y_k}.$$

Comment: will $x_n=\frac{1}{2n \pi + \pi /2}$ $y_n=-x_n$ work?

Comment: They will not work. $\sin(\frac{1}{x_n})=1$ which is perfect, but $\sin(\frac{1}{y_n})=-1$ and $y_n<0$. Hence $y_n^{r-1} \sin(\frac{1}{y_n})=-y_n^{r-1}\rightarrow \infty$. $y_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ works a bit better.